# Reading article doesn't require subscription when coming from google?

Tags: browser, web, subscription

This is weird but must be something simple which yet baffles me.

I'm reading an article on the FT site. If I get to this article via google search, I can read it. If I get to the same article by pasting its address, it just shows me the title and requires subscription for reading.

Just to be more clear:

1. I open Chrome (the same happens with Firefox though)
2. I make a google search for that article's title, then I click on the result and then the article page is shown
3. I copy its address, and paste it on a new tab, this time the page shows just the title and requires subsciption for reading
4. Now I have the same pc, same connection, same browser, two tabs with the same site address, yet very different pages

Why?

I tried many times with the same results.

The same happens if I reach the article via bing, instead reaching from duckduckgo or yahoo shows me the article title only and requires subscription.

Tried with Chrome v80 and Firefox v75 both without any extension.

Comment: Google has read the article and cached the results.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not supposed to access google cached results when accessing a website. And what do you mean with read? Google "reads" most of the web... it would be nice if bypassing subscription would just require coming from google, but of course this doesn't work on all other news sites I usually visit, which are still indexed by google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options:

1. This is a regular web page but the server checks the HTTP **"Referer:"** header to determine where you came from. Some sites offer a few free articles to visitors from search engines as a "try before you buy" thing.

   This logic is implemented in the website, and can work with any search engine (or any linking site in general) that the site owners decide to allow. (They probably don't care about DDG.)
2. This is a Google AMP format page which is allegedly faster-loading than regular web pages. One of its features is that AMP pages can be cached by Google as a fully self-contained bundle – when you click on a search result you're sometimes just downloading the cached copy and not actually contacting the original site. Such a page cannot know whether you're a subscriber, it just has the same content no matter who visits it.

   This technology is Google-specific.

Comment: The site does have AMP version but I wasn't accessing via mobile. Besides, it happens with Bing as well. Option 1 instead seems the right one and as a matter of fact, after having read some articles thanks to google referer, it's now showing the subscription page, but can still access via Bing referer. Needless to say that's a very weird way of "asking" subscription.